# Calculate the azimuth between two points given the latitude and longitude are known with VBA

Tags: vba, function, excel

I have to calculate the azimuth between two points given in latitude and longitude
is this fynction correct?

```
Function azimut(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2)

azimut = WorksheetFunction.Degrees(WorksheetFunction.Atan2(
   Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(lat1)) * 
   Sin(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(lat2)) -
   Sin(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(lat1)) * 
   Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(lat2)) * 
   Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(lon2 - lon1)), 
   Sin(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(lon2 - lon1)) * 
   Cos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(lat2))))

End Function
```

Comment: Well you tell us if it is correct or not? What values you were expecting and what did you exactly get :) Since you are new here, I would recommend visiting [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then rewording your question

Comment: Is you question about the code or about the validity of the formula you are using?

Comment: it is about the validity of the formula...

Comment: in fact, I want to determine the adjacens radio sites like 3G sites. now I have to determine the cells in a half circle in front bounded by the perpendicular to the direction of the cell (azimuth) and a radius which is configurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your formula is correct (since I interpret it to the code below without checking it), then here is the code:

```
Function Azimuth(lat1 As Single, lat2 As Single, lon1 As Single, lon2 As Single) As Single

Dim X1 As Single, X2 As Single, Y As Single, dX As Single, dY As Single

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    X1 = .Radians(lat1)
    X2 = .Radians(lat2)
    Y = .Radians(lon2 - lon1)
End With

    dX = Math.Cos(X1) * Math.Sin(X2) - Math.Sin(X1) * Math.Cos(X2) * Math.Cos(Y)
    dY = Math.Cos(X2) * Math.Sin(Y)


With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Azimuth = .Degrees(.Atan2(dX, dY))
End With

End Function
```

Well, even if the formula turns out to be incorrect, at least the code above should give you the idea to start with.